# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' in small app

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to build an Android project (it is a small project), and I am getting this error in Travis:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I am aware I can fix this problem by enabling multiDex, however I don't think this error should happen in my case, as I don't believe the project and its dependencies surpass the method limit for multiDex.

Here are the dependencies in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':geth')
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You exceeded 65536 methods. Maybe this :geth project is too big?

You can turn multidexing on, more info here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

You can check what part of your project taking too much method indexes with:

https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin